# Fetch data, store it inside of an observable and use it inside of a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to fetch some data and display it within a list. The fetching part works, but I somehow haven't figured how to get it to the list's view.

My approach was to create an observable inside of `FirebaseSession` and call this observable inside of my view. - Somehow, no data appears though.

I don't think there's a problem with the view's code, since I tested it before using static data.

```
struct HomeList: View {
    @State var showContent = false
    @State private var selectedShelter: Shelter?

    @ObservedObject var session = FirebaseSession()

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            HStack {
                HomeListTitle()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 35) {
                    ForEach(self.session.shelters) { item in
                        ShelterView(title: item.title, background: item.image, available: item.available, distance: item.distance, gender: item.gender ?? "")
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.showContent.toggle()
                                self.selectedShelter = item
                        }
                        .sheet(item: self.$selectedShelter) { item in
                            ShelterDetailedView(shelter: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FirebaseSession: ObservableObject {

    @Published var shelters: [Shelter] = []

    let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("shelters")

    func getShelters() {
        ref.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, err in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(err!)")
                return
            }
            for document in documents {
                let value = document.data()
                if let shelter = Shelter(id: value["id"] as? String ?? "", title: value["title"] as? String ?? "", image: value["image"] as? String ?? "", available: value["available"] as? Bool ?? false, distance: value["distance"] as? Double ?? -1, gender: value["gender"] as? String ?? "") {
                    self.shelters.append(shelter)
                } else {
                    print("Provided data is wrong.")
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        ...

        let session = FirebaseSession()
        session.getShelters()

        return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're loading the data into one instance of `FirebaseSession` and trying to use them from another.

In your `AppDelegate`, you create a variable named `sessions` and do `sessions.getShelters()`. This variable is not currently used outside of the method in which it is defined.

Separately in `struct HomeList`, you create a different variable with

```swift
@ObservedObject var session = FirebaseSession()
```

but never run `getShelters()`.

Consider using

```swift
onAppear { self.session.getShelters() }
```

in your `HomeList` view to get the shelters loaded.

```swift
// ...
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            HStack {
                HomeListTitle()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 35) {
                    ForEach(self.session.shelters) { item in
                        ShelterView(title: item.title, background: item.image, available: item.available, distance: item.distance, gender: item.gender ?? "")
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.showContent.toggle()
                                self.selectedShelter = item
                        }
                        .sheet(item: self.$selectedShelter) { item in
                            ShelterDetailedView(shelter: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear { self.session.getShelters() }
    }
// ...
```

Comment: It works thanks - hence I can get rid of the functions inside of AppDelegate?